# WordPress categories endpoint giving error 404

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress blog, [Librarier](https://librarier.com).

**PROBLEM**

It's giving me an error when we try to access some of the categories. But it works perfectly on others categories.

for example, these categories don't work:

https://librarier.com/category/lifestyle/

https://librarier.com/category/health/

this category does work:

[https://librarier.com/category/health/](https://librarier.com/category/book/)

**WHAT'S I'VE BEEN TRIED**

1. Change category base on permalinks setting
   As some articles told me to do so
   [image]

**Others**
When I tried to change only the case sensitivity on the endpoint, it works.

https://librarier.com/category/lifestyle/ (error 404)

https://librarier.com/category/Lifestyle/ (working)

**NOTE**
WordPress: 5.7.1

(Theme)
Veen: 2.1.1

(Plugins)

All-in-One WP Migration: 7.4.2

LiteSpeed Cache: 3.6.4

Site Kit by Google: 1.31.0

Veen Theme Functions: 2.1.4

WPForms Lite: 1.6.6

WPS Hide Login: 1.8.5

Yoast SEO Premium: 15.5

Comment: Seems to work fine now, how did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: redirect https://librarier.com/category/lifestyle/ to https://librarier.com/category/Lifestyle/ via editing the .htaccess file